# Querying the Global Address List (GAL) via Exchange Web Services (EWS) erreor SSL

Tags: c#, contacts, exchangewebservices

My English is not good but I'll do my best.
I try to access Exchange 2010 via EWS, I want to get the contacts of a mailbox
Reading emails in the inbox works perfectly

Here is my code and thank you in advance for your response

```
class Program
{   
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(Object obj, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors errors)
        {
            // If the certificate is a valid, signed certificate, return true.
            if (errors == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None)
            {
                return true;
            }
            // If there are errors in the certificate chain, look at each error to determine the cause.
            if ((errors & System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors) != 0)
            {
                if (chain != null && chain.ChainStatus != null)
                {
                    foreach (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatus status in chain.ChainStatus)
                    {
                        if ((certificate.Subject == certificate.Issuer) &&
                           (status.Status == System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatusFlags.UntrustedRoot))
                        {
                            // Self-signed certificates with an untrusted root are valid.
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (status.Status != System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError)
                            {
                                // If there are any other errors in the certificate chain, the certificate is invalid,
                                // so the method returns false.
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                // When processing reaches this line, the only errors in the certificate chain are
                // untrusted root errors for self-signed certificates. These certificates are valid
                // for default Exchange Server installations, so return true.
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                // In all other cases, return false.
                return false;
            }
        };

        ExchangeService _service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
        _service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("user", "password");
        _service.Url = new Uri("https://mail.domain.be/ews/exchange.asmx");

        //Mail dans mailbox
        FindItemsResults<Item> findResults =  _service.FindItems(
        WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(10));

        foreach (Item item in findResults.Items)
            Console.WriteLine(item.Subject);
        Console.ReadLine();

         //CONtact mailbox
        foreach (Contact contact in _service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts, new ItemView(int.MaxValue)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(contact);
        }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(Object obj, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors errors)
    {
        if (errors == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if ((errors & System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors) != 0)
        {
            if (chain != null && chain.ChainStatus != null)
            {
                foreach (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatus status in chain.ChainStatus)
                {
                    if ((certificate.Subject == certificate.Issuer) &&
                       (status.Status == System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatusFlags.UntrustedRoot))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (status.Status != System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError)
                        {

                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }; 

    ExchangeService _service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
    _service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("user", "password");
    _service.Url = new Uri("https://mail.domain.com/ews/exchange.asmx");

    //Contact mailbox
    ContactsFolder contactsfolder = ContactsFolder.Bind(_service, WellKnownFolderName.Contacts);

    int numItems = contactsfolder.TotalCount < int.MaxValue ? contactsfolder.TotalCount : int.MaxValue;

    ItemView view = new ItemView(numItems);

    view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ContactSchema.DisplayName);

    FindItemsResults<Item> contactItems = _service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts, view);

    foreach (Item item in contactItems)
    {
        if (item is Contact)
        {
            Contact contact = item as Contact;
            Console.WriteLine(contact.DisplayName);
        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```